# How do I put this into an expression "For any nonzero real number $x$, there exist $-x$ real number."?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I put this into an expression "For any nonzero real number $x$, there exist $-x$ real number."? Is it "$\forall x\ne0 \exists(-x)$"?

I don't know how to put "real number $x$" into an equation

Comment: It is half-correct. Simply write $\forall x\neq 0. \exists -x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are trying to do is to formulate the statement that every number $x$ has an additive inverse, denoted $-x$.

A better way to do this is to separate the *statement* from the *definition of the notation*, like this:

- $\forall x \in \mathbb R \,\,\exists y \in \mathbb R$ such that $x+y=0$. Denote $-x=y$.

However, this raises a logical issue: how do we know that $-x$ is well-defined?

To answer that, one must also state (and prove) uniqueness:

- $\forall x, y, y' \in \mathbb R$, if $x+y=0$ and $x+y'=0$ then $y=y'$.

Only after that is done is it logically valid to introduce a well-defined notation for the additive inverse.